# Grunt concat no errors but doesn't works

Tags: gruntjs

Hi Grunt concat doesn't shows errors, but it doesn't concentrate my styles.css file. Here is a screenshot of it:

link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xftGJ.png

And here is a screenshot of my css file, which still isn't being concatenated(also you can see my folder structure here below):

link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCw4L.png

And here is my gruntfile.js (Maybe I should have a different separator in concat_css.):

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    less: {
      development: {
        options: {
          compress: true,
          yuicompress: true,
          optimization: 2,
          css: ['concat']
        },
        files: {
          "css/styles.css": "css/styles.less" // destination file and source file
        }
      }
    },
    concat_css: {
      options: {
        // Task-specific options go here.
        separator: '}'
      },
      all: {
        src: ["css/styles.css"],
        dest: "css/styles.css"
      },
    },
    watch: {
      styles: {
        files: ['css/styles.less'], // which files to watch
        tasks: ['less', 'concat_css'],
        options: {
          nospawn: true
        }
      }
    }
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-concat-css');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['less', 'watch', 'concat_css']);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the task is called `concat`, not `concat_css`. You're config will need to match that name (that is, you should not be using `concat_css` at all). Aside from that, why would you make the separator the closing brace (`}`)? If you ever have more than one file that will almost certainly cause a syntax error in the concatenated CSS file. I would leave out that option unless you have a specific need for it.

```
concat: {  // <-- change this to match the name of the task: "concat"
  all: {
    src: ["css/styles.css"],
    dest: "css/styles.css"
  },
},
```

Comment: nope it's called concat_css, I saw that from this link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-concat-css But I think I don't need that plugin, because your answer on my other question did the trick. If I set compress to 'false'. Then it will concentrate my css file :) .

Comment: Aah, yes. It helps to specify which plugin you're using (the other one is `grunt-contrib-concat`, which is better, IMO).